# AndroidTest does not use test application

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-testing

Hi I faced that when I rewrite application in androidTest manifest file, it does not work. This is my `AndroidManifest.xml` file in `androidTest` folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="ru.app"
    android:installLocation="auto">

  <application
      tools:replace="android:name"
      android:name=".app.ApplicationAndroidTest" />

</manifest>
```

This is part of original `AndroidManifest.xml` from `main` folder:

```
<application
        android:name=".app.Application"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme">
...
</application>
```

In fact I debugged it, and called getApplication() from breakpoint in activity under test, it returns `.app.Application` instead of `ApplicationAndroidTest` instance.

Do you have any ideas why android manifest file from androidTest is ignored?

Answer (score 5):

As A workaround I used custom test runner class:

```
public class UiTestsRunner extends AndroidJUnitRunner {

  @Override
  @NonNull
  public Application newApplication(@NonNull ClassLoader cl, @NonNull String className, @NonNull Context context)
          throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException {
    return Instrumentation.newApplication(ApplicationAndroidTest.class, context);
  }
}
```

It seams ok for me. Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Changing application class at androidTest xml doesn't affect the app itself (tested app) but the additional android test apk that ships to the device for enabling tests. I'm not sure what is the exact meaning of application if any to android test apk.

anyhow [busylee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2156937/busylee) workaround is the available solution.
Important note: when defining custom instrumentation runner, it is required to run the tests with the custom runner, that can be done at Android Studio by editing run configuration of test run, under AndroidTests section with a test selected, there is 'Specific instrumentation runner (optional)' option.

Comment: I tried this approach, but the manifest values defined in the androidTest weren't being merged into the final manifest (perhaps this used to work, but it no longer appears to). An alternative would be to create a 'uiTest' flavour with the test manifest, though I would instead recommend creating a custom AndroidJUnitRunner.